# Handling incoming webhook with signature

Tags: php

My Code:

```
        if($payload = file_get_contents('php://input')) {
            try {
                $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', $payload, 'my_secret'));
                $is_valid = hash_equals($signature, $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SHOPPY_SIGNATURE']);

                $data = json_decode($payload);

                if($is_valid) {
                    // do stuff
                    } else {
                        http_response_code(400);
                    }
                }
            } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                http_response_code(400);
                echo 'Error occured. ' . $exception->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

It just doesnt give me any informations. I have tested it with just `Storage::put('test.txt', $data);` but it doesnt work.

If I put the Storage::put code above the signature check it gives me the whole payload, so I guess something is wrong with the signature here. The Webhook  simulator is also giving me the response that everything is fine.

Their documentation (https://shoppy.dev/#webhooks) is also showing a different example, but if I use it, I get errors like "Error occured. Undefined index: X-Shoppy-Signature" or "Error occured. hash_hmac() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given".

Do I have to enable something first in php in order to check the signature?

Comment: 'doesnt work' as in, you get a blank page? What happens if you replace `// do stuff` with  `echo "It works!";`

Comment: I have code in there, also as already said, the Storage::put works fine when before the signature check, but not after the check or inside the if($is_valid) query

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', $payload, 'my_secret'));
$is_valid = hash_equals($signature, $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SHOPPY_SIGNATURE']);
```

doesnt need base64_encode

So just do

```
$signature = hash_hmac('sha512', $payload, 'my_secret');
$is_valid = hash_equals($signature, $_SERVER['HTTP_X_SHOPPY_SIGNATURE']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `Laravel`, try this

```html
public function getwebhook(Request $request) {
    
    try {
        $signature = hash_hmac('sha512', $request, 'my_secret');
        $is_valid = hash_equals($signature, $request->header('X-Shoppy-Signature'));

        $data = json_decode($request);

        if($is_valid) {
            // do stuff
            } else {
                http_response_code(400);
            }
        }
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo 'Error occured. ' . $exception->getMessage();
    }
    
}
```